# Iterate through Hashtable containing List of values in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to print Keys and a list of values together in a single string in powershell.

I have something like this
`List(dict(key:value)) (key= string , value=list<String>)`
so my input is like this

```
dict(
 "apple"=$list1
 "banana"=$list2
 "orange"=$list3)
$list1=@('red','green')
$list2=@('yellow','black')
$list3=@('orange')
```

Now I want output something like that:

```
$Final_ans= apple,red_green banana,yellow_black orange,orange
```

How can I do this in PowerShell? I am not able to iterate like this.
I tried few methods but it is giving me output System Collection.HashTable

Comment: What's with the python-esque pseudocode? Do you actually have any (working) code, or is this something you're imagining?

Comment: I am working on powershell module and I have this scenario so I am unable to iterate like this. I am new to powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a hashtable or dictionary where all keys are strings and the value entries are arrays of strings, like this:

```
$list1 = @('red','green')
$list2 = @('yellow','black')
$list3 = @('orange')

$hashtable = @{
  "apple" = $list1
  "banana" = $list2
  "orange" = $list3
}
```

(`@{}` is PowerShell's native syntax for a hashtable (an unordered dictionary) literal.)

You can enumerate each key/value pair like this:

```
$hashtable.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Key     # this will resolve to the key (ex. "apple")
  $_.Value   # this will resolve to the values (ex. @('red', 'green'))
}
```

So to construct a string like the one you describe, we can do something like this:

```
@($hashtable.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Key,($_.Value -join '_') -join ','
}) -join ' '
```

Here, we use the `-join` operator to concatenate the individual strings with different delimiters:

`$_.Value -join '_'` turns the value pairs (ex. `@('red', 'green')`) into a string like `red_green`

`$_.Key,(...) -join ','` turns the key + string we created in the previous step into a string like `apple,red_green`

`@(...) -join ' '` then turns all of those strings into one big space-separated string `apple,red_green banana,yellow_black orange,orange`